# I'm trying to get list of all updated files on pull request using github actions inside github-action variable

Tags: linux, github, github-actions

I actually wants to get all file names which are updated while pull request. I'm using github action, so I want all updated file names should come in one variable.
If anyone can help me on getting all updated file names in one variable in github actions will be great.

I tried doing:

```
    # Make sure we have some code to diff.
  - name: Checkout repository
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Get changed files
    id: changes
    # Set outputs using the command.
    run: |
      echo "::set-output name=all::$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} ${{ github.sha }} | xargs)"
      echo "::set-output name=ts::$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.sha }} ${{ github.sha }} | grep .ts$ | xargs)"
```

lint:
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
# require the first job to have ran
needs: changedfiles
# only run there are changed files
if: ${{needs.changedfiles.outputs.ts}}
steps:
- name: echo changed files
run: echo ${{needs.changedfiles.outputs.ts}}

got error saying:

error: Could not access 'f57a9fe09ef4538dcae55e7a5d5b2761d562760f'
/home/aakha2/actions-runner/_work/_temp/03d4c98c-6167-4e4f-ad93-0af8b01c3213.sh: line 3: run:: command not found
error: Could not access 'f57a9fe09ef4538dcae55e7a5d5b2761d562760f'